# Is it possible to expose an HTTP proxy on localhost via ngrok?

Tags: proxy, curl, http-proxy, tinyproxy

I have `tinyproxy` installed on localhost (I also tried `squid` and failed similarly). It runs on port 8888. This works:

```
curl -x localhost:8888 http://www.google.com
```

And I see output in the tinyproxy logs.

Now I run the latest version of `ngrok` and get the following forwarding established:

```
http://<identifier>.ngrok.io -> localhost:8888
```

If I open `http://<identifier>.ngrok.io` on my browser the ngrok connection counter goes up, and I successfully see tinyproxy's "not implemented" error page.

However, this fails:

```
curl -x <identifier>.ngrok.io:80 http://www.google.com
# => curl: (56) Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT
```

The ngrok counter does not go up, and I do not see messages in the tinyproxy logs, suggesting that the failure is before ngrok accepted the connection.

What am I missing here? I had assumed that both ngrok and tinyproxy forward the HTTP request, but it seems like there might be another protocol operating behind the scenes of `curl -x`. Is there a way to successfully establish the proxy chain starting at ngrok and going through my localhost?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the exact same issue right now...

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is accurate. All you need to do is run the following tcp command instead of http command:

```
ngrok tcp 8888
```

It will create a tcp tunnel and print something like this:

```
tcp://something.ngrok.io:18673 -> localhost:8888
```

You can then use it like this.

```
curl -x something.ngrok.io:18673 http://www.google.com
```